# Speeding up Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Currently I am working on a real-time plot but the visualization is really slow. I would like to know what things in general you can do to speed up things in Matplotlib:

- How does the backend affect the performance? Are there backends that
  are better for real time plotting than others?
- Can I lower the resolution to increase FPS?
- Why does the FPS of my plot increase if I reduce the window size? Why
  does FPS drop dramatically if I switch to full screen mode?

I also tried to turn off everything I don't need:

```
ax.set_xticklabels(())
ax.set_yticklabels(())
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.axis('off')
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```

However, the effect is negligible. Are there more things I can turn off?

I would also like to know if it is possible to turn off the buttons (home button, etc.., see below) of the window that opens when creating a graph. May turning off these buttons increase the speed?

[image]

I also found that doing the following

```
fig.canvas.draw_idle()
fig.canvas.start_event_loop(1e-9)
```

is much slower for updating the plot than

```
fig.canvas.draw_idle()
self.fig.canvas.update()
self.fig.canvas.flush_events()
```

Are there even better ways to update the objects in a plot?

Comment: try to do it by multithread your cpu

Comment: Can you give a simple example? Would you draw the objects using Python's multiprocessing toolbox?

Answer (score 1):

> How does the backend affect the performance? Are there backends that are better for real time plotting than others?

The backend plays two roles: First, it renders everything, so the faster it renders, the faster the output. Second, the GUI toolkit used may play a role, because it may limit how fast an updated canvas is displayed. It seems `"Qt5Agg"` is faster than `"TkAgg"` for example.

> Can I lower the resolution to increase FPS?

You can make the figure smaller, or use a smaller dpi. Both will decrease the amount of pixels that need to be drawn and hence speed up drawing.

> Why does the FPS of my plot increase if I reduce the window size? Why does FPS drop dramatically if I switch to full screen mode?

As above, more pixels that need to be drawn on screen mean slower rendering.

> Are there more things I can turn off?

We don't know what you have in your code, so we can't know what to turn off.

> May turning off these buttons increase the speed?

No.

---

Finally, `fig.canvas.draw_idle()` in itself should be sufficient to update the plot, because usually you would have the event loop running already. Restarting an event loop is not helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried to lower the resolution using `rcParams["figure.dpi"] = 50`. Now, however, many objects are just much smaller. How do I correctly lower the amount of pixels that need to be drawn?

Comment: That's the purpose of lowering the figure size or dpi. I don't think this will lead anywhere without a concrete [mcve] of the issue.